# Что такое динамическое связывание в PHP?

Tags: php

Что такое "динамическое связывание" в PHP? Объясните простым языком, пожалуйста.

*Термин встречен в книге Робина Никсона, глава 4, подраздел Динамическое связывание в PHP - 115 страница.*

Comment: А где вы нашли такой термин?

Comment: В книге Робина Никсона два параграфа описано, а я не могу понять что это такое

Comment: Укажите конкретную главу, пожалуйста.

Comment: Четвертая глава - подраздел Динамическое связывание в PHP - 115 страница.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Очень странный перевод того, что описывает автор в данном параграфе. 
Я так понимаю, что автор имеет в виду что в идеале сайт стоит рассматривать и разрабатывать как набор нескольких независимых модулей, или как сейчас говорят - сервисов. Каждый из сервисов решает свою конкретную задачу и код модуля (сервиса) располагается в отдельном php-файле. 
Таким образом у вас нет огромной простыни непонятного кода и дальнейшая поддержка и тестирование упрощается.

Comment: да сильно похоже из того что там написано

Answer (score 3):

Это действительно не имеет никакого отношения к какому-нибудь позднему статическому связыванию (late static binding), в оригинале употребляется слово ***linking***. Очевидно, в этом месте автор переходит от однофайловых примеров к многофайловым и объясняет, почему этот переход осуществляется. Все, что автор описывает в этих двух абзацах - почему необходимо разбивать приложения на файлы и как это работает на пальцах.